# \Omega not working in math mode [Workaround]

Tags: math-mode

I have a problem typing in math mode. Every symbol seems to work without any flaws, yet the command \Omega in math mode results in a . instead of a symbol. Every other symbol works without problems.

```
\documentclass{tudelft-report}
\usepackage{mcode}        % allows for matlab code copy pasting
\usepackage{fixltx2e}     % used for subscript in text
\usepackage{rotating}     % used for rotating text (sideways tables) and figures
\usepackage{hhline}       % allowing for broken double lines
\usepackage{printlen}
\usepackage{amsmath}      % used for numbered matrices check if needed!!!
\usepackage{breqn}        % splitting equations over multiple line (matrices)
\usepackage{epstopdf}     % used for importing EPS matlab figures
\usepackage{pdflscape}    % in combination with \begin{landscape} shows the page in landscape both in content as in the PDF
\usepackage{longtable}
```

above my active packages. If anyone could be able to help it would be really appreciated. The problem is solved.

WorkAround:
using `\varOmega` seems to have enabled me to draw the Omega symbol.

---

Example

```
\begin{equation}
  %eq:rotDimVel
  \mu_{pre cor,i}=\frac{1}{{\Omega{}}_iR_i}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    u_{r,i}\\ v_{r,i}\\ w_{r,i}
  \end{bmatrix}
    = \frac{1}{\Omega_iR_i}
      \left(
        \begin{bmatrix}
          u_{heli}\\
          v_{heli}\\
          w_{heli}
        \end{bmatrix}
        +
       \begin{bmatrix}
         0 & z_{r,i} & {-y}_{r,i} \\
         -z_{r,i}& 0 & x_{r,i} \\
         y_{r,i} & {-x}_{r,i} & 0 
       \end{bmatrix}
       \begin{bmatrix}
         p_{heli}\\
         q_{heli}\\
         r_{heli}
       \end{bmatrix}
     \right)
  \label{eq:rotDimVel}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Please fix your code section so that it includes an `\Omega` that does not work, then we can test locally. Also remove non standard packages such as mcode if the problem still occurs without them, to make it more likely we can help.

Comment: the \Omega code is everywhere...

Comment: There seems to be an incompatibility between one of the packages loaded by the class (which is not on CTAN, so I assume you've used https://github.com/praseodym/tudelft-report-latex/blob/master/tudelft-report.cls) and the `breqn` package, if you remove `breqn` it works fine. A minimal example showing the problem is `\documentclass{tudelft-report}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
$\Omega$
\end{document}`.

Comment: Which font is the class using? AFAIR breqn use special setup files for fonts and only a few fonts are supported

Comment: The `tudelft-report` class uses the Fourier fonts, which are not supported by `breqn`, because they use different font encodings for the math fonts.